# ¿Por qué no aparecen todos los datos de la tabla con PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, php8

Tengo una tabla y una página con código. Antes de pasar al problema y a la pregunta dejen les planteo el procedimiento.

**Procedimiento**

Se tienen los siguiente elementos:

*Lista sin numerar 1.1*

- una base de datos con su respectiva tabla
- un archivo .php saca los datos de la tabla (se le conocerá a futuro como "codigo")
- un servidor (xampp)

El código puede acceder a la base de datos para sacar información y verificar que sí funciona la conexión. A su vez puede acceder a los datos de la tabla en la db.

Primero se hizo un `fetchAll()` de toda la tabla y el resultado de vaciar los datos de la tabla con el método **FetchAll** es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
*imagen 1.1*

Para mayor legibilidad vea la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
*imagen 1.2*

Se tomó en cuenta los datos que se quieren utilizar de la tabla para este ejercicio indicados en la siguiente lista:

*lista numerada 1.2*

1. sub_id
2. sub_tipo
3. nombre
4. usuario
5. status

Iniciando sesión con una cuenta (debe ser de la tabla en la db) solo deja sacar información del usuario  y solo del usuario. Por ejemplo, si entro con una cuenta aparece lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
*imagen 1.3*

Se intentó [este tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894933/create-profile-information-page-in-php-mysql-pdo) sin éxito alguno.

El código es el mostrado a continuación:

```php
    <?php session_start();
        
    $host = '127.0.0.1';
    $db = 'jobction';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $charset = 'utf8mb4';
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $options = [
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
      PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
      PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    global $host, $db, $user, $pass, $charset, $dsn, $options;
        try
        {
          $conexion = new PDO($dsn,$user,$pass,$options);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
          throw new PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
        }
    $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND pass = :pass ');
    $statement->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario);
    $statement->bindParam(':pass', $password); 
    $statement->execute();
      $resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    var_dump($_SESSION);

    ?>
```

*código 1.1*

Por recomendación de **A.Cedano** se agregó un **var_dump($_SESSION)** para observar el comportamiento de las variables de sesión el cual es el indicado en el siguiente texto:

```php
array(1) { ["usuario"]=> string(15) "trolo@gmail.com" }
```

*código 1.2*

**Observaciones**

Parece ser que el resultado de usar `var_dump($_SESSION)` nos dio un arreglo que contiene un solo elemento a pesar que en esta sección se le está pidiendo que nos muestre uno más que es `pass`:

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND pass = :pass ');
$statement->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario);
$statement->bindParam(':pass', $password); //<-- aqui
```

*código 1.3*

**Planteamiendo del Problema**

Con todo lo expuesto anteriormente y las condiciones que se necesitan que se muestre con base en la lista numerada 1.1 el planteamiento es el siguiente: aparte de mostrar el usuario, ¿cómo se podría sustraer los datos descritos en la lista numerada 1.1 y mostrarlos en pantalla?

Comment: *pero yo quiero también la información del password o del id o incluso del status del que inicio sesión*. Bien, y ¿dónde está esa información? ¿se supone que en la variable `$resultado`? Muéstrala mediante el código. Ahora mismo sólo estás mostrando esto: `echo "bienvenido, " . $_SESSION['usuario'] . "! ";` y eso es lo que verás, como es lógico, porque no muestras nada más.

Comment: si yo le agrego abajo del  echo '"bienvenido, " . $_SESSION['usuario'] . "! "'; 
 y le agrego un:  

echo "contraseña, " . $_SESSION['password'] . "! "; me sale Warning: Undefined array key "pass" in C:\xampp\htdocs\pagina_stps\stps\profile.php on line 35
bienvenido, ! :/

Comment: No es posible que diga `Undefined array key "pass"` cuando la key que usas es `password`. Considera que debes usar las keys tal y como se llamen. Si no sabes como se llaman pon un `var_dump($_SESSION);` para ver lo que hay en tu variable de sesión y cómo se llaman las keys. Sea como sea, no queda claro en la pregunta qué es lo que quieres mostrar.

Comment: ya se edito todo para que quedara mas claro lo que se busca con la pregunta

Comment: Disculpa mi pesadez, pero tu pregunta sigue siendo bastante confusa, hay que hacer un gran esfuerzo para tratar de entender el asunto. Como bien te muestra el `var_dump`, en tu variable de sesión no hay nada más. ¿No será que los otros datos que buscas están en la base de datos, concretamente en `$resultado`? Prueba a hacer un `var_dump($resultado);` y dinos qué muestra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que tu error está aquí:

```php
$resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Estás pasando como argumento `PDO::FETCH_NUM` por lo que estás indicando que querés recibir un array cuyos índices sean numéricos.

Cita textual de la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php):

> **PDO::FETCH_NUM** devuelve un array indexado por el número de columna tal como fue devuelto en el conjunto de resultados, comenzando por la columna 0.

Por lo que deberías usar `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` para recibir un array con las claves asociadas a los nombres de dichas columnas.

> **PDO::FETCH_ASSOC** devuelve un array indexado por los nombres de las columnas del conjunto de resultados.

Así te debería quedar la línea:

```php
$resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

O también podés usar la función [setFetchMode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php) antes del [execute](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php).

```php
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND pass = :pass ');
$statement->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario);
$statement->bindParam(':pass', $password); 
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // así
$statement->execute();
$resultado = $statement->fetch();
```

Respondiendo a:

> ...aparte de mostrar el usuario ¿Cómo se podría sustraer los datos descritos en la lista numerada 1.1 y mostrarlos en pantalla?

El `usuario` es una columna así que, para que te muestre también las demás deberías indicar una a una en el `select` de la consulta o usar el `*` (asterisco).

Pero esto ya lo estás haciendo:

```php
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND pass = :pass ');
```

Así que deberían aparecer todas las columnas.

Y por último, para que te imprima el resultado podrías usar [echo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.echo) y la función [print_r](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.print-r) de php.

```php
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND pass = :pass ');
$statement->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario);
$statement->bindParam(':pass', $password); 
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$statement->execute();
$resultado = $statement->fetch();

echo '<pre>', print_r($resultado); // Imprime el resultado en pantalla
```

Comment: ya vi si era eso, puse lo que recomendaste y funciono muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Saludos yo uso este archivo como conexión a BD

```
     $contraseña = " tu contraseña";
     $usuario = "tu usuario";
     $nombre_base_de_datos = "tu bd";
     try{
         $bd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $nombre_base_de_datos, $usuario, $contraseña);
     }catch(Exception $e){
            echo "Ocurrió algo con la base de datos: " . $e->getMessage();
     }
```

y luego lo siguiente para usarlo

```
function tufuncion($usuario,$pass){
        include ('elarchivo-conexion.php');
        $sql="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = $usuario AND pass = $pass";
        $result=$bd->query($sql);
        foreach ($result as $datos){
           // lo que desees hacer 
            $datos ['campo1']
            $datos ['campo2']
        }
        $bd=null;  
    }
```

verifica y quizás te sirve